# Looking for "consumer that returns value" abstraction in Java

Tags: java, producer-consumer, abstraction, functional-interface

Is there a built-in or robust third-party abstraction for consumer that returns value in Java 8+?

**P.S.** For deferred execution it may return *Future* as well.

**Update.** *Function* interface has a perfect syntactic match, but there is a consideration around semantics. Using *Function* in this case obviously breaks *don't change external state* piece of contract. How to deal with that?

Comment: You mean a function?

Comment: You can use a `Function` that consumes its argument and returns whatever value you need.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Comment: For the deferred version, that would be `Function<T, CompletableFuture<R>>`. You can then compose/chain these things together. If a particular implementation does not actually need to defer, it can return an already completed future with the result.

Comment: There is nothing in the Java type system that prevents code from "changing external state". You'll have to look at the Function implementations  and their documentations yourself. I suppose you could find an "effect system" (like Scala ZIO), but those are quite exotic in Javaland (and even they cannot really enforce functional purity).

Comment: Someone made a `@SideEffectFree` annotation https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/dataflow/qual/SideEffectFree.html

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for the `Function<T, R>`-interface. It is generic and takes a parameter, while returning a value. it can be used for lambda expressions, for example mapping:

```java
Integer input = 1;
Function<Integer, Integer> myMapping = a -> a * 2;
Integer myInt = myMapping.apply(input);
// myInt == 2
```

Take a look at the java util.function package: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

There is a multitude of different predefined functional interfaces. `@FunctionalInterface` is the annotation marking such interfaces that definitely only have exactly one non-default method. Such interfaces can be used for lambda expressions.

here are some top candidates:

- Consumer: Takes one parameter, returns void.
- Function: Takes one parameter, returns a value.
- Supplier: Takes nothing, returns a value.
- Predicate: Takes one parameter and returns a boolean.

and the various derivations thereof.

All of these can be stored as "values", to be later executed. In a sense, they can become callbacks, if needed.

Edit:
Because a `Function` is not expected to change the external state of it's execution, some applications for APIs seem tricky. However, if you intend to use a function in this fashion, you could define a parameter-class which is basically a wrapper for all values expected to be changed. If any of them is changed during execution, the external state is updated based on those changes. However this seems to be more of a pattern, than a simple one-class/interface langauge feature. I used parameter classes before, even before lambda expressions, and it works well, if the right javadocs are properly described.

Comment: I did see your update, and would ask, that you specify, what exactly you mean. The contract of which interface requires *don't change external state*? Also: A function cannot change external state, other that by return value, or by modifying an object. A Function can never be prevented, for example, to modify an argument `Collection` or array, unless you pass an unmodifyable `Collection`. You simply can't technically prevent it. It should, however, be prevented by contract. May I ask what exactly your use case is? It would help a lot in answering your underlying question.

Comment: There is no technical limitation either for *Predicate* or *Function* to change external state. But doing so seems to go against *best practices* and potentially creates problems with thread-safety and can cause memory leaks. On the other hand *Consumer* is expected to change state. So my concern is more about good practices for writing good and robust code than about technical limits of the language.

Comment: Oh I get it. Your use case requires an Input and output, but you *need* to change external state (or explicitly allow for it) and want to signify this? In that case, you can extend the `Function` interface with an interface that is expressly allowed (and expected) to modify the external state. You could call it `VolatileFunction` or something thelike. More in my edit.